# Does Jaccard similarity index's denominator include intersection?

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics

I have met some contradiction in definition of Jaccard similarity. Jaccard similarity formula is:
$$J(A, B) = \frac{|A \cap B|}{|A \cup B|}=\frac{|A \cap B|}{|A| + |B| - |A \cap B|}$$

So as we see intersection of $A$ and $B$ is discluded from denominator. However on this image from Wikipedia page about Jaccard similarity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index ) where this formula above is written intersection is not discluded:

[image]

So which definition os right?

Answer (score 1):

Both the image and the formula are correct. In general you have $\vert A\cup B\vert \leq \vert A \vert + \vert B\vert$ and the equality holds when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.
You can write $A = (A\cap B) \cup (A \setminus B)$ and $B =  (A\cap B) \cup (B \setminus A)$. This implies $$\vert A \vert + \vert B\vert = 2 \vert A\cap B\vert + \vert A \setminus B\vert +  \vert B \setminus A\vert.$$ On the other hand $$\vert A\cup B\vert = \vert (A\cap B) \cup (A\setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)\vert=\vert A\cap B\vert + \vert A\setminus B\vert + \vert B \setminus A\vert,$$
where the last equality holds because the sets are disjoint.
This gives you
$$ \vert A \vert + \vert B\vert-\vert A\cup B\vert = \vert A\cap B\vert,$$
which is what they used in the second equality of the definition you posted.
I think the confusion was caused by seeing $\vert A\cap B\vert$ subtracted, but expanding $\vert A \vert + \vert B\vert$ as above, you can see that $\vert A\cap B\vert$ is counted twice so you need to remove one of them to get the same result you would get from $\vert A\cup B\vert $, which is correctly represented by the denominator in the image.